# How to make non-sibling elements have the same height in React

Tags: css, reactjs

Is it possible to make **non-sibling** elements to have the same height (the height of the tallest one) in React?

That obviously cannot be done with CSS. That would be fairly easy to do with JavaScript but I'd have to rely on `DOMNodeInserted` event since the elements I'm working with are dynamic and I'm pretty sure that wouldn't work with React.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

With a pure React solution, you have to redesign your CSS, or redesign your React component hierarchical.

Or you can use a state manager like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) or [Alt](http://alt.js.org/). If your application is not too big, I recommend Alt since it is simpler.